# Xamarin Forms Hardware Button CrossPlateform

Tags: button, xamarin.forms, hardware

I don't find any solution or explaination to use the **BackButton hardware** (Android & WinPhone 8.1) from MyPage, defined in the **PCL** part.

Is it possible to handle that button from a Portable Class Library?

Thank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is. You can ovveride default behaviour for back button in pcl. For example if you want to deactivate it, you can use in the page you want:

```
        protected override bool OnBackButtonPressed()
        {
                return true;
        }
```

Comment: Thank ! if I return false, it let the button has the normal behavior?

Comment: yes, and you can add your extra functionality there